# backpack for laravel can't modify text inside td when ajax is enabled

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-backpack

I 'm using backpack crud for laravel and i'm trying to modify the displayed text inside cells on a list, when ajax is disabled, jquery does its job , but i need ajax enabled for showDetailsRow, so is there any way to change the X on the image for icons using jquery when ajax is enabled on the crud??

jquery :

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

   $(".parametro tr>td:nth-child(n+4):contains('X')").html('<span class="ion-android-done"></span>');

  });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [creating a custom Backpack column](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-columns-types#section-roll-your-own). You can use the boolean column code as example and just show the icon you want instead of true/false.

I think this would be faster and cleaner than using jQuery.